# Putting text using cv2.putText() outside a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv

I want to put values of area on top of the rectangle. I tried many ways, but failed

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
pic=cv2.imread('multiple.jpg')
picGray=cv2.cvtColor(pic,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
picBlur= cv2.GaussianBlur(picGray, (21, 21), 0)
_,contours,_=cv2.findContours(picBlur,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours=np.array(contours)
for i in range(len(contours)):
area=cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
print(area)
for cnt in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(pic,cnt,-1,(0,255,0),2)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(pic,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.putText(pic,str(area),(x,y-5), font, .5,(255,255,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow('pic',pic)
```

Image file 'multiple.jpg'

[image]

Comment: Your indentation is off in the example for the for-loops. And why do you us both `for i in range(len(contours)):` and `for cnt in contours:`? Could you achieve the same thing with just the last for-loop?

Answer (score 3):

The code below works for me.

```
import cv2

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
pic=cv2.imread('multiple.jpg')
picGray=cv2.cvtColor(pic,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
picBlur= cv2.GaussianBlur(picGray, (21, 21), 0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(picBlur,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for cnt in contours:
    area=cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    print(area)
    cv2.drawContours(pic,cnt,-1,(0,255,0),2)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(pic,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
    cv2.putText(pic,str(area),(x,y-5), font, .5,(255,255,255),1,cv2.CV_AA)
cv2.imshow('pic',pic)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I adapted:

- the first for-loop,
- changed `_, contours, _` to `contours, hierarchy` (so your output of `contours` wasn't correct, at least for my version of openCV, 2.4.13.6),
- skipped the `np.array(contours)` line and
- added `cv2.waitkey()` (necessary when using `cv2.imshow()`!!) and `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`